# how to parse the complecate JSON

Tags: json

I want get the  "text": "#12062" these value only in the below json list

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "textAngle": 0,
  "orientation": "Up",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "251,234,341,436",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "320,234,227,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "320,238,52,19",
              "text": "#12062"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "383,245,24,16",
              "text": "106"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "417,248,51,18",
              "text": "SILVER"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "478,241,45,25",
              "text": "THREAD"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "532,234,15,19",
              "text": "LN"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "346,256,185,27",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "346,256,61,20",
              "text": "BRANSON"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "417,264,40,19",
              "text": "WEST,"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "469,268,16,15",
              "text": "MO"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "494,256,37,24",
              "text": "65737"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "390,277,104,22",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "390,277,104,22",
              "text": "417-272—1112"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "345,298,235,35",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "345,304,35,17",
              "text": "9303"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "408,310,32,17",
              "text": "0021"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "460,308,82,25",
              "text": "01/10/2018"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "551,298,29,22",
              "text": "g:41"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "256,294,25,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "256,294,25,17",
              "text": "277"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "257,331,335,33",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "257,334,16,12",
              "text": "<<"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "283,331,26,16",
              "text": "BUY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "320,332,5,15",
              "text": "1"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "336,335,27,15",
              "text": "GET"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "374,338,5,14",
              "text": "1"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "391,341,87,21",
              "text": "EQUAL/LESS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "487,348,43,16",
              "text": "VALUE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "569,333,23,20",
              "text": "Off"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "256,349,290,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "256,350,35,16",
              "text": "CLAY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "301,349,41,17",
              "text": "4-1Nl"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "355,351,25,17",
              "text": "FCL"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "390,356,52,19",
              "text": "CLOTHS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "452,363,34,16",
              "text": "SENS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "496,366,16,14",
              "text": "RF"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "522,362,24,19",
              "text": "333"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "540,375,30,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "540,375,30,21",
              "text": "8.49"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "479,381,8,14",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "479,381,8,14",
              "text": "A"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "292,386,151,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "292,386,52,17",
              "text": "RETURN"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "354,386,44,17",
              "text": "VALUE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "408,390,8,14",
              "text": "6"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "426,391,17,16",
              "text": "36"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "256,401,293,30",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "256,404,35,17",
              "text": "OLAY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "301,404,41,17",
              "text": "4-1Nl"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "355,404,25,16",
              "text": "FCL"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "390,401,53,22",
              "text": "CLOiHS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "453,410,34,18",
              "text": "NRML"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "497,414,16,15",
              "text": "RF"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "523,416,26,15",
              "text": "33S"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "292,422,97,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "292,422,97,17",
              "text": "07560904127"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "541,429,34,18",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "541,429,34,18",
              "text": "4.24"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "292,440,160,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "292,440,62,17",
              "text": "REGULAR"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "364,440,43,17",
              "text": "PRICE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "417,440,35,17",
              "text": "8.49"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "292,458,178,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "292,459,62,16",
              "text": "REWARDS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "364,459,61,16",
              "text": "SAVINGS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "435,458,35,17",
              "text": "4,25"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "292,476,151,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "292,476,53,17",
              "text": "RETURN"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "355,477,43,16",
              "text": "VALUE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "408,477,35,16",
              "text": "6.37"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "255,494,296,19",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "255,494,36,16",
              "text": "OLAY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "300,495,42,16",
              "text": "4-1Nl"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "355,495,25,16",
              "text": "FCL"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "390,495,53,17",
              "text": "CLOTHS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "454,495,34,17",
              "text": "NRML"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "498,496,17,16",
              "text": "RF"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "525,498,26,15",
              "text": "33S"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "291,512,98,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "291,512,98,17",
              "text": "07560904127"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "543,515,34,18",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "543,515,34,18",
              "text": "8.49"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "291,530,152,18",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "291,530,53,16",
              "text": "RETURN"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "354,531,44,16",
              "text": "VALUE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "408,532,35,16",
              "text": "6.36"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "254,546,297,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "254,546,35,16",
              "text": "OLAY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "299,548,43,16",
              "text": "4-1M"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "354,549,26,16",
              "text": "FCL"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "390,549,53,17",
              "text": "CLOTHS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "452,550,36,16",
              "text": "SENS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "497,550,18,16",
              "text": "RF"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "525,550,26,17",
              "text": "339"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "290,565,98,18",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "290,565,98,18",
              "text": "07560904128"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "542,568,35,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "542,568,35,17",
              "text": "4.24"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "289,582,162,19",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "289,582,63,17",
              "text": "REGULAR"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "362,584,44,16",
              "text": "PRICE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "416,585,35,16",
              "text": "8.49"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "289,600,180,18",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "289,600,63,17",
              "text": "REWARDS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "362,602,62,16",
              "text": "SAVINGS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "434,602,35,16",
              "text": "4.25"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "289,617,152,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "289,617,53,16",
              "text": "RETURN"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "352,619,44,15",
              "text": "VALUE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "406,619,35,15",
              "text": "6.37"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "251,651,244,18",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "251,651,36,16",
              "text": "OLAY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "297,652,42,16",
              "text": "4-1Nl"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "352,652,43,16",
              "text": "FCLC"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "423,653,27,16",
              "text": "MFG"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "460,654,35,15",
              "text": "ECPN"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "533,653,44,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "533,653,44,17",
              "text": "-5.00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "249,702,205,159",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "284,702,73,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "284,702,73,17",
              "text": "SUBTOTAL"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "283,719,165,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "283,719,46,16",
              "text": "SALES"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "339,720,27,15",
              "text": "TAX"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "375,721,73,15",
              "text": "A-8.475%"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "282,753,44,16",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "282,753,44,16",
              "text": "TOTAL"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "282,771,90,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "282,771,44,17",
              "text": "DEBIT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "337,771,35,16",
              "text": "CARD"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "281,789,54,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "281,789,54,17",
              "text": "CHANGE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "249,824,205,20",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "249,825,58,18",
              "text": "BALANCE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "317,824,63,17",
              "text": "REWARDS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "390,825,64,19",
              "text": "SAVINGS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "250,842,157,19",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "250,845,23,16",
              "text": "MFG"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "281,843,53,17",
              "text": "COUPON"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "344,842,63,18",
              "text": "SAVINGS"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "530,706,46,159",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "531,706,45,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "531,706,45,17",
              "text": "20.46"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "542,724,34,16",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "542,724,34,16",
              "text": "1.73"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "530,758,46,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "530,758,46,17",
              "text": "22.19"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "530,776,45,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "530,776,17,16",
              "text": "22"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "552,788,2,4",
              "text": "."
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "560,777,15,16",
              "text": "19"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "551,795,24,16",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "551,795,24,16",
              "text": ".00"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "538,830,37,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "538,830,37,17",
              "text": "8.50"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "538,848,37,17",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "538,848,37,17",
              "text": "5.00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "247,877,321,171",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "249,877,316,25",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "249,881,38,16",
              "text": "THANK"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "298,880,27,16",
              "text": "YOU"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "336,877,26,17",
              "text": "FOR"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "372,878,71,20",
              "text": "SHOPPING"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "453,882,18,17",
              "text": "AT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "481,883,84,19",
              "text": "WALGREENS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "279,913,235,27",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "279,915,36,19",
              "text": "MORE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "325,913,37,17",
              "text": "WITH"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "372,914,61,20",
              "text": "BALANCE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "443,919,71,21",
              "text": "REWARDS,"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "307,931,236,24",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "307,931,54,18",
              "text": "POINTS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "372,932,25,16",
              "text": "FOR"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "407,935,81,20",
              "text": "SOMETHING"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "499,940,44,15",
              "text": "EXTRA"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "270,949,282,25",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "270,955,9,16",
              "text": "A"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "290,949,53,20",
              "text": "FUTURE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "353,949,77,21",
              "text": "PURCHASE."
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "443,955,109,19",
              "text": "RESTRICTIONS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "344,967,187,28",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "344,967,44,17",
              "text": "TERMS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "398,970,25,17",
              "text": "AND"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "433,972,98,23",
              "text": "CONDITIONS,"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "247,984,247,27",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "247,990,41,19",
              "text": "VISIT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "299,984,195,27",
              "text": "WALGREENS.COM/BALANCE."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "310,1020,258,28",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "310,1021,32,19",
              "text": "RFN#"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "354,1020,214,28",
              "text": "1206-2219-3035-1801-1003"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "252,1167,225,166",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "389,1167,48,15",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "389,1167,48,15",
              "text": "balance•"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "377,1179,100,28",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "377,1179,100,28",
              "text": "eward"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "256,1242,25,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "256,1242,25,21",
              "text": "SAV"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "254,1255,102,44",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "254,1272,42,27",
              "text": "POINT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "303,1255,53,29",
              "text": "BALANCE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "252,1290,165,43",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "252,1305,50,28",
              "text": "POINTS"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "311,1297,14,19",
              "text": "TO"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "331,1290,25,18",
              "text": "$10"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "365,1293,52,20",
              "text": "REWARD"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "533,1221,58,106",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "535,1221,56,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "535,1221,56,32",
              "text": "u.50"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "534,1269,36,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "534,1269,36,21",
              "text": "8550"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "533,1306,34,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "533,1306,34,21",
              "text": "1450"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "236,1325,325,239",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "250,1325,181,43",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "250,1337,59,31",
              "text": "BALANCE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "381,1328,34,20",
              "text": "ACCT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "423,1325,8,14",
              "text": "#"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "527,1380,34,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "527,1380,34,21",
              "text": "1300"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "524,1398,27,19",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "524,1398,27,19",
              "text": "250"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "312,1399,58,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "312,1399,58,32",
              "text": "BALANCES"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "524,1415,35,22",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "524,1415,35,22",
              "text": "7000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "522,1434,36,21",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "522,1434,36,21",
              "text": "8550"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "326,1476,42,22",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "326,1476,42,22",
              "text": "12062"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "237,1503,173,44",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "237,1512,67,35",
              "text": "{OJENCE"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "323,1503,87,25",
              "text": "2062210120"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "236,1520,174,44",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "236,1532,59,32",
              "text": "PAYMENT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "305,1527,35,19",
              "text": "FROM"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "349,1520,61,18",
              "text": "PRIMARY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please re-format so it is readable, and tell us more, like what language you are using, what error you get exactly, and show us all of the code

Comment: I need Only all the text value "text": "NOTHING",  "text": "EXISTS","text": "EXCEPT"  also please refer the url, json formated text available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/javascript-print-text

Comment: You forgot to answer the question about what language you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the programming language you want your answers in. Also, questions on Stack Overflow must include everything necessary to reproduce the problem (a [mcve]), not a link to those necessary things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code(use Newtonsoft.Json)

```
string contents = "";//json string

        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(contents)))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Value != null)
                {
                    if (reader.Value.ToString().Equals("#12062"))
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",
                                          reader.TokenType, reader.ValueType, reader.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no indication the OP is using C# or .NET.